# Rails, pow and Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rack-pow

I didn't work on this rails app for a couple of weeks. Yesterday I got back to it, first opening the .dev URL (i'm using pow) and it gave this error message:

`LoadError: dlopen([...]/vendor/bundle/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib
  Referenced from: [...]/vendor/bundle/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
  Reason: image not found - [...]/vendor/bundle/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle`

I checked the rbenv install and all seemed fine. I tried to think of recent changes that could lead to this but I can't. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something but my attempts to debug it were futile. I don't know if it's relevant but I recently switched to zsh.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Solution

Uninstall and reinstall sqlite:

```
~/d/w/r/my-app git:master ❯❯❯ gem uninstall sqlite3                                                                      

Successfully uninstalled sqlite3-1.3.7

~/d/w/r/my-app git:master ❯❯❯ gem install sqlite3                                                                            
Fetching: sqlite3-1.3.7.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.7
1 gem installed
```

### What Happened

When the sqlite3 gem is installed, it builds a native component for talking to **sqlite** and so it links against the local **sqlite3** libraries. This is all handled behind the scenes by *gem*. When that happens, it specifies the location of the library that it linked against.

Recently (January), [the **homebrew** formula for **sqlite** became keg-only](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/17000). Anything that was previously linked against **sqlite** referenced the homebrew version. You can check this by using `otool -L`:

```
~/d/w/r/my-app git:master ❯❯❯ otool -L /path/to/earlier/gem/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
/path/to/earlier/gem/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle:
    /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.6.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

Running `otool` against the new version you can see that it is now linked against the Apple-provided system sqlite libraries:

```
~/d/w/r/a/new-config git:master ❯❯❯ otool -L /path/to/new/gem/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
 /path/to/new/gem/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle:
    /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.6.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```